# Modification of the Prestashop 1.7 search engine, '-' '' characters,

Tags: php, search, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need help with search engine in Presta 1.7, I hope I will find a good soul to help me out.
When I want to search for example: VR-50HD, EVOLVE 50 and I type the exact same thing in the search engine, it is all perfect, same situation when I use space instead of dash (VR 50HD). 
The problem occurs when phrases are without any punctuation marks like VR50HD, EVOLVE50. It's like product does not exist.

Another problem I got is with the results of the search engine. When searching VR-50HD, engine will add a lot of products where "50" appears in the product or even the category.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your first problem using aliases. Go to search preferences and enter VR50HD as an alias for VR-50HD.

Your second problem is caused by "Search within word" option. You need to disable it.

You can read more about it at [Prestashop documentation, Search parameters](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Search+parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Aliases will be difficult to make because there are too many products, so it will be difficult to enter the combination manually. I would prefer to modify the search engine so that it would deal with '-' and spaces.

Comment: You should add this as a comment not as an answer. Anyway, what you want to do is not possible with Prestashop only. You will need Elasticsearch installation and a Prestashop module to connect it to Elasticsearch. At least two modules can do it: [ElasticsearchConnector](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/search-filters/19527-elasticsearchconnector.html) and [Elastic Jet Search](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/search-filters/30078-elastic-jet-search.html).